# Using shared elements transition between activities with different orientations

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, shared-element-transition, activity-transition

I have an Activity A which is permanently set in landscape orientation and an Activity B without any predefined orientation.

If I start activity B from activity A and phone rotation is in a landscape angle, shared element transition works properly and activity B starts in landscape orientation as expected. The problem occurs if the phone rotation is in a portrait angle, during the start of Activity B. Then, Activity B starts in portrait orientation (as expected) but no transition happens.

Has anyone faced this problem problem before? Any help would be appreciated.
This is how activity B is called from Activity A:

`Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sharedView,sharedViewTransitionName);
startActivity(mIntent,options.toBundle());`

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this library for activity and fragment transitions for pre lollipop devices. This supports scene transitions

```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.albinmathew:PreLollipopTransition:1.1.2'
```

}

https://github.com/albinmathew/PreLollipopTransition

Comment: cant add dependencies file...!!